# Dynamic array, which can also be saved to file

Tags: android

In my Android application, I need to make a list of favorite items. Each of these items consists of 3 key/value pairs. I want a dynamic array capable of:

- Insertion at end only
- Sortable
- Deletion at any point
- Can be saved to File

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) sounds perfect given your requirements.

> The [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) class provides a general framework that allows you to save and retrieve persistent key-value pairs of primitive data types. You can use [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to save any primitive data: booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings. This data will persist across user sessions (even if your application is killed).

Answer (score 0):

Use `ArrayList` for the first 3 dots, for the last, override the `toString()` method and write the result to a file.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel when Android provides [plenty of existing, good options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)?

Comment: He said nothing about the purpose of the array, shared preferences used for shared preferences and it's not correct to use it as a general storage. the second option in the link you posted is actually my suggestion: internal data storage which is a file in the sandbox.